# Microsoft Office 2010 keeps freezing after Windows 7 cloning

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, freeze, clone, deployment

I clone Windows 7 installation with all programs together with Microsoft Office 2010. After applying image to new PC - all Office programs freeze after a few minutes of running and I have to force closing them. It's KMS license.

In the past I was cloning whole partition without using sysprep, but now I do it right way: I install Windows, press CTRL+SHIFT+F3 when asked to input username and then I install all Windows Updates, programs and Office 2010. After that I run sysprep with generalize, OOBE and shutdown options, so I can capture image using ImageX. I replace install.wim image in Windows ISO image and than install Windows 7 on different PCs. After that I install all drivers, migrate to Active Directory and everything works, but Office still keeps freezing. 
Other programs which I install before capturing image: Adobe Reader, Adobe Flash Player, Citrix Presentation Server Client, Java, Microsoft Lync 2010, 7-zip, printer driver and I don't have any problems with them.

I don't rearm Office before capturing image (as was wrote in Microsoft tutorial), but I'm not sure if it may be the reason. If I don't apply image, but install Windows and then all the same drivers and programs, then everything is ok.

I disabled all add-ins, but it doesn't help. Reinstalling or repairing also doesn't help. Only solution is to install Office 2013, but I must use 2010. Do you have any idea what can be the reason or how I can diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a proxy and when MS Office tried to activate, it didn't respond for very long time. Disabling the proxy helped.